# Mount files in read-only volume (where source is in .dockerignore)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My app depends on secrets, which I have stored in the folder `.credentials` (e.g. `.credentials/.env`, `.credentials/.google_api.json`, etc...) I don't want these files built into the docker image, however they need to be visible to the docker container.

My solution is:

- Add `.credentials` to my .dockerignore
- Mount the credentials folder in read-only mode with a volume:

```
# docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./.credentials:/app/.credentials:ro
```

1. This is not working (I do not see any credentials inside the docker container). I'm wondering if the `.dockerignore` is causing the volume to break, or if I've done something else wrong?
2. Am I going about this the wrong way? e.g. I could just pass the `.env` file with `docker run IMAGE_NAME --env-file .env`

Edit:

My issue was to do with how I was running the image. I was doing `docker-compose build` and then `docker run IMAGE_NAME`, assuming that the volumes were build into the image. However this seems not to be the case.

Instead **the above code works** when I do `docker-compose run app`(where app is the service name) after building.

Comment: Have you tried to create `/app/.credentials` during build image process? That will make sure  `/app/.credentials` exists on your container before you map  a volume to it.

Comment: I just tried that out, adding `RUN mkdir /app/.credentials` in my Dockerfile. After this, I see the directory in the container but no contents.

Comment: What steps are you using to verify the container has started with the above compose file settings? How are you verifying the file does not exist inside the container? How are you running the docker engine?

Comment: @BMitch I build a test image which runs a sleep script, and run with `docker run IMAGE_NAME`. In a new window, I connect with `docker exec CONTAINER_ID bash` and look around

Comment: You can run docker-compose exec app ls -la /app. It should work. Which type of OS do you use?

Comment: The `docker run` command does not use the compose file, so your volume will not be mounted.

Comment: @BMitch You were right. It works as expected when I do `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose run app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, the issue here is in looking at the `docker-compose.yml` file for your container definition while starting the container with `docker run`. The `docker run` command does not use the compose file, so no volumes were defined on the resulting container.

The build process itself creates an image where you do not specify the source of volumes. Only the Dockerfile and your build context is used as an input to the build. The rest of the compose file are all run time settings that apply to containers. Many projects do not even use the compose file for building the image, so all settings in the compose file for those projects are a way to define the default settings for containers being created.

The solution is to using `docker-compose up -d` to test your `docker-compose.yml`.